# TightVNC to Windows 7: Password?

Tags: networking, remote, vnc

I installed tightvncserver on my Pi

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
```

Now to run tightvnc server I do

```
tightvncserver
```

I get

```
New 'X' desktop is raspberrypi:7

Starting applications specified in /home/pi/.vnc/xstartup
```

Now from windows 7, I open TightVNC viewer. I put pi's IP address in Remote host box.
[image]

I click on connect. I get.

[image]

Now what password is being prompted here? I never entered any password? I tried raspberry pi's password, blank password but both failed. What do I have to enter here. Did I miss any steps?

Comment: I am pretty sure the default is no password, just press OK

Comment: tried it not working

Comment: DId you run tightvncserver on the Pi?  It prompts you to enter a password.

Comment: it didn't prompt. I  had to set it by running `vncpasswd`. After that it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set password for VNC. Type **vncpasswd** in tight vnc server's terminal (i.e raspberry). Give a password and then try to login your pi.

Comment: Thanks. Missed the setting of password part. Are there any settings that I have to do when I run the tightvncserver?